# How to print the right number of asterix in columns and rows?

Tags: java

I want to print asterix which is equals the number of rows - (they should begin from the right side). It should begin with 9 spaces and 1 * at the first line, then 2 * and 8 spaces at the second line and so on until the tenth row which should have 10 * and 0 spaces like the image below:

[image]

I can print the right number of spaces at each line and 1 * at the right position. For example it prints 9 spaces and 1 * at the first line. But then at the second line it prints 8 spaces and 1 * at the ninth position instead of two?? I can't see what I have missed in my code:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    for (int col = 10; col > row; col--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        if (col <= row) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

Comment: `if (col <= row)` should never happen with the condition in the `for`

Comment: That is because I was trying to figure it out..

Comment: Given the way you're approaching this, change `col > row` to `col > 1`, then move `print(" ")` into new `else` on the `if` statement. That'll get you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1) Either you create two inner loops for each row: one to write the spaces and another to write the stars

```
    final int rows = 10;
    for(int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (rows - row); i++) {
             System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < (row); i++) {
             System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

2) Or you create one inner loops for each row and check the index to consider if you have to print a star or a blank.

```
final int rows = 10;
for(int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    for(int col = 1; col <= rows; col++) {
         System.out.print((col <=(rows - row))? " " : "*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

3) Or you can use string manipulation with `subString` (this is ugly but why not):

```
final int rows = 10;
final String stars = "************************";
final String blanks = "                        ";
for(int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    System.out.print(blanks.substring(0, rows - row));
    System.out.println(stars.substring(0, row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also be helpful:

```
    int n = 10;
    int k = 2 * n - 2; // number of spaces
    // outer loop to handle number of rows
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // inner loop to handle number spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
            System.out.print(" "); // printing spaces
        }
        k = k - 2; // decrementing k after each loop
        // inner loop to handle number of columns
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("* "); // printing stars
        }
        // ending line after each row
        System.out.println();
    }
```